# java - Get 4 strings from another string and check which one is different

Tags: java, string

I am very sorry for the unclear title but I have no idea how to explain what I want to do.

Basically, I have this string:

```
<li>
 <span id="correctAnswer1748">Answer1</span>
</li>
<li>
 <span>Answer2</span>
</li>
<li>
 <span>Answer3</span>
</li>
<li>
 <span>Answer4</span>
</li>
```

(It doesn't really say what answer number the answer is, it displays different text.)

(The span id = "correctAnswer1748" can be any four numbers (from 1-1803.))

There are many lines like this but with different answers and different correct answers. 
now, I want to get Answer1, Answer2, Answer3 and Answer4 and keep them in the same order, and an int to tell me which one is correct, the first one, the second one, the third one or the fourth one.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Some kind of HTML/XML parser looks like it should do the job.

Comment: how are u identifying which answer is correct?

Comment: One of many usefull tools: http://jsoup.org/

Comment: @John I am trying to get the one that has <span id=correctAnswer with any four numbers after the correctAnswer.

Comment: you could try some HTML/XML parser. Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are asking, but what I understood is, you want to compare part of this string in java.

You could use some String methods like:

you save your string in a String variable, then you save can use those methods (assuming the variable is called "text":

```
int index1 = text.indexOf(char character);
String substring1 = text.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex);
```

this for every answer and then to compare:

```
boolean isEqual = substring1.equals(String substring2);
```

I hope that's what you asked for, and it helped you.